# ASP.NET Core : HtmlHelper extension (migration issue)

Tags: c#, html-helper, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to update some code in a old MVC-project (.NET Framework 4.5.2) to work with .NET Core 2.2. I got stuck on a extension method of HtmlHelper that is generating a link inside a string.

```
public static HtmlString GetMenu(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
   htmlString += string.Format("<li{0}>{1}</li>",
            controller == "Examples" ? " class=\"selected\"" : "",
            htmlHelper.ActionLink("Examples", "Index", "Examples")
        );
}
```

The HtmlHelper class are found inside the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures in .NET Core, but the method ActionLink want more information. Instead of 3 arguments as in the old project, it now wants 8 arguments, and two of these are protocol and hostname. But I am not sure how to get hostname and protocol in a static class, without accessing the HttpContext.

Comment: There is a ViewContext property of the IHtmlHelper interface that has HttpContext property you can inspect.

Comment: Are you sure about this? According to the documentation, there should be an overload that only takes 3 arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, the class that was previously called `HtmlHelper` has now been replaced by the interface **`IHtmlHelper`**.

This means that all the link extensions (`HtmlHelperLinkExtensions`) have switched to the interface as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperlinkextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2